# Need help building bash file. Instructions and Examples Enclosed

Tags: bash, automation, backup

I am trying to build a (what seems to me) complex bash file and would like help knowing how to write it. I would like to learn how, I'm not asking for you guys to do it for me :)

Instructions:

```
#Step 1.
#Copy Folder1 from InstallDrive:\(install.directory) to BackupDrive:\(backup.directory)
##Name Copied Folder1 to *Current Date*-Folder1
#Copy Folder2 from InstallDrive:\(install.directory) to BackupDrive:\(backup.directory)
##Name Copied Folder2 to *Current Date*-Folder2
#!!!Confirm Files Were Copied fully!!!
#Delete Folder1 from InstallDrive:\(install.directory)
#Delete Folder2 from InstallDrive:\(install.directory)
#Delete Folder3 from InstallDrive:\(install.directory)
#Step 2.
#Launch Program
##Login
##Let Run for x minutes
##Exit/Terminate Program
#Step 3.
#Copy most current *Current Date* Folder1 from BackupDrive:\(backup.directory)\ to InstallDrive:\(install.directory)
#Copy most current *Current Date* Folder2 from BackupDrive:\(backup.directory)\ to InstallDrive:\(install.directory)
```

Any help or direction would be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `cp`=copy, `mv` (move)=rename, `rm`(remove)=delete. Be carefule with `rm`. Also, your example shows typical MS Windows path info, ie InstDr:\instDir. For linux or Cygwin installations of bash, use `/path/to/file` notation. Your requirement for 'let run for x minutes' would be (comparatively) an advanced requirement. Get some results with `cp, mv, rm` and then post a new question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Great, now you know my dirty little secret. lol

This is what I have so far:

```
#Step 1.
___________________________________________________________________________

#Copy Folder1 from InstallDrive:\(install.directory) to BackupDrive:\(backup.directory)
cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Games\World of Warcraft\WTF\." "H:\wow.wtf.interface.backup.DND\WTF\." -R

##Name Copied Folder1 to *Current Date*-Folder1
#How do I make a dynamic date?
#How do I rename the file in the BackupDrive:\()BackupDirectory)?

#Copy Folder2 from InstallDrive:\(install.directory) to BackupDrive:\(backup.directory)
cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Games\World of Warcraft\Interface\." "H:\wow.wtf.interface.backup.DND\Interface\." -R

##Name Copied Folder2 to *Current Date*-Folder2
#How do I make a dynamic date?
#How do I rename the file in the BackupDrive:\()BackupDirectory)?

#!!!Verify Files Were Copied fully!!!
#How do I do this?

#Delete Folder1 from InstallDrive:\(install.directory)
rm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Games\World of Warcraft\WTF\."

#Delete Folder2 from InstallDrive:\(install.directory)
rm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Games\World of Warcraft\Interface\."

#Delete Folder3 from InstallDrive:\(install.directory)
rm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Games\World of Warcraft\Cache\."

#Step 2.
___________________________________________________________________________

#Launch Program
start "Battle.Net" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Battle.net Launcher.exe"
start "World of Warcraft" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Games\World of Warcraft\Wow-64.exe"
##Login
*User Input*
##Let Run for x minutes
?
##Exit/Terminate Program
end "Battle.Net" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Battle.net Launcher.exe"
end "World of Warcraft" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Games\World of Warcraft\Wow-64.exe"

#Step 3.
___________________________________________________________________________

#Copy most current *Current Date* Folder1 from BackupDrive:\(backup.directory)\ to InstallDrive:\(install.directory)
cp "H:\wow.wtf.interface.backup.DND\WTF\." "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Games\World of Warcraft\WTF\." -R

#See question at ##Name Copied Folder1 to *Current Date*-Folder1

#Copy most current *Current Date* Folder2 from BackupDrive:\(backup.directory)\ to InstallDrive:\(install.directory)
cp "H:\wow.wtf.interface.backup.DND\Interface\." "C:\Program Files (x86)\Battle.net\Games\World of Warcraft\Interface\." -R

#See question at ##Name Copied Folder2 to *Current Date*-Folder2
```

Edit: Why was I voted down?

Comment: (I didn't downvote, but) This shouldn't be posted as an answer. 1 theory here on S.O. for this situation is to add a section below your initial Q labeled **edit** and then paste all of this. The other theory is to post another question. My theory is to edit your original question, delete anything that is not covered in this answer, paste your answer into your question, save, and then delete this "answer". Also, please remove the dash lines or prefix with a `#` character so people can copy paste your code and just run it, without any editing required.

Comment: You can get the current date into a variable with `myDate=$(/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d)`. Then use it like `cp -p c:\.... h:\backupDirs\$myDate\moreDirs` . Not sure what you mean by "Dynamic date", a date passed in as an argument on the cmd line? Or do you prompt the user "What date do you want to use"? ... You also want to use `man rm`, `man cp` , `man mv` to read the "man(ual)" pages for each of these commands. There are some options that may be appropriate for you. Finally, I would recommend posting smaller questions. This is starting to feel like free consulting ;-) . ... OK? Good luck.

Comment: I'm so sorry for getting the format incorrect. I am very new here and new to simple "programming" like bash ( if you even want to call it that). I originally posted it as an edit, but then changed it again as you can see, because I was unsure as to the format. Also, I come from Tom's Hardware where long posts are necessary. Again, thank you for the advice and your help and guidance.

Comment: you can verify `cp` produced no errors with either `if cp src targ ; then echo "no errors" ; else echo "got RC=$?, indicating an error" ; fi OR `cp src targ; rc=$? ; case $rc in 0 ) echo "no errs" ;;* ) echo "got RC=$rc ; error!";; esac`
For your remaining questions, you might do better to trim things down to 1 problem per posting, and show that you have researched what is available here on S.O. Good luck.